# How to count the number of occurrent of each user ID with conditions in SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a table in MS SQL that collects the status of each ID in a marketing campaign. In each month, there is a column to check that each consumer ID is in the marketing campaign or not (`is_in_programme`), if so, in each month, are they newcomers in our programme or not (`is_new_apply`). Each ID can apply in the programme in multiple times.

My table contains datetime (reported in the last day of every month, with no skipped month), ID, status of each ID as I stated above. And I want to check that in each period, how many time that each ID is in this programme (on `EXPECTED` column).

In my `Output` column, I've tried to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function that partitioned by `id`, `is_in_programme`, `is_new_apply` when `is_in_programme`, `is_new_apply` are both 1. But I cannot check the occurent of each ID when `is_new_apply == 0`

```
+------------+-------+-----------------+--------------+--------+----------+
|  datetime  |  ID   | is_in_programme | is_new_apply | Output | EXPECTED |
+------------+-------+-----------------+--------------+--------+----------+
| 31/01/2020 | 12345 |               1 |            1 |      1 |        1 |
| 29/02/2020 | 12345 |               1 |            0 |      0 |        1 |
| 31/03/2020 | 12345 |               1 |            0 |      0 |        1 |
| 30/04/2020 | 12345 |               1 |            0 |      0 |        1 |
| 31/05/2020 | 12345 |               0 |            0 |      0 |        0 |
| 30/06/2020 | 12345 |               1 |            1 |      2 |        2 |
| 31/07/2020 | 12345 |               1 |            0 |      0 |        2 |
| 31/08/2020 | 12345 |               1 |            0 |      0 |        2 |
| 31/01/2020 | 67890 |               0 |            0 |      0 |        0 |
| 29/02/2020 | 67890 |               1 |            1 |      1 |        1 |
| 31/03/2020 | 67890 |               1 |            0 |      0 |        1 |
| 30/04/2020 | 67890 |               0 |            0 |      0 |        0 |
| 31/05/2020 | 67890 |               0 |            0 |      0 |        0 |
| 30/06/2020 | 67890 |               1 |            1 |      2 |        2 |
| 31/07/2020 | 67890 |               1 |            0 |      0 |        2 |
| 31/08/2020 | 67890 |               1 |            0 |      0 |        2 |
| 30/09/2020 | 67890 |               0 |            0 |      0 |        0 |
| 31/10/2020 | 67890 |               1 |            1 |      3 |        3 |
| 30/11/2020 | 67890 |               1 |            0 |      0 |        3 |
| 31/12/2020 | 67890 |               1 |            0 |      0 |        3 |
+------------+-------+-----------------+--------------+--------+----------+
```

Is there any way to check that how many time that each ID is in the marketing campaign in each period like my `EXPECTED` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a cumulative sum of `is_new_apply` when `is_in_program` is not `0`.  That would be:

```
select t.*,
       (case when is_in_program <> 0
             then sum(is_new_apply) over (partition by id order by datetime)
             else 0
        end) as expected
from t;
```